# Python: compilng VideoCapture to onefile exe

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller

im trying to compile my py script to onefile EXE with pyinstaller
everything working great except the "VideoCapture" lib.
this is the block in my code with videocapture:

```
def TakePicture(s):
try:
    cam = VideoCapture.Device(0)
    cam.saveSnapshot("C:\\Users\\Public\\pic.jpg")
    s.send("Snapshot saved at Users\Public\pic.jpg\n")
except Exception as camerror:
    print camerror

s.send("Checking for second camera ...\n")
time.sleep(6)
try:
    cam2 = VideoCapture.Device(1)
    cam2.saveSnapshot("C:\\Users\\Public\\pic2.jpg")
    s.send("Snapshot saved at Users\Public\pic2.jpg\n")
except Exception as camerror2:
    print camerror2
```

everything working great when i running the script as py but after compiling to exe
i get an error "cannot find font file"

what can i do to make it one file EXE that works?
thanks.

Problem Solved

all i need to do is edit "load_path" function in this file: Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py
orginal code:

```
def load_path(filename):
"Load a font file, searching along the Python path."
for dir in sys.path:
    if Image.isDirectory(dir):
        try:
            return load(os.path.join(dir, filename))
        except IOError:
            pass
raise IOError("cannot find font file")
```

edit code:

```
def load_path(filename):
"Load a font file, searching along the Python path."
for dir in sys.path:
    if Image.isDirectory(dir):
        try:
            #return load(os.path.join(dir, filename))
            return load_default()
        except IOError:
            pass
raise IOError("cannot find font file")
```

Comment: What font file can't it find? If you have the font name, include it in your data directory before running pyinstaller.

Comment: i dont have .. this is the exception i get "cannot find font file"

Comment: I think you should paste the complete console output.

Answer (score -1):

```
def load_path(filename):
"Load a font file, searching along the Python path."
for dir in sys.path:
    if Image.isDirectory(dir):
        try:
            #return load(os.path.join(dir, filename))
            return load_default()
        except IOError:
            pass
raise IOError("cannot find font file")
```

It worked,thanks a lot!